# Error Cross origin requests

Tags: nodejs, express

Tratando de consumir un servicio a través de un web app que tengo alojada en **heroku**, me parece el siguiente error:

```
Failed to load localhost:3000/posts/1: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

He revisado lo relacionado con los `CORS` y he probado dos formas diferente

`app.use(cors());`

y esta otra

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});
```

Estoy usando en mi caso `json-server` para crear un API sencilla para pruebas, ya que el servicio viene de una **API** la cual esta alojada en **Azure**, y me salia eso, asi que decidi probar, y sale tambien consumiendo desde otra forma.

Comment: Estas cargando una pagina desde heroku y en la pagina haces una llamada ajax a localhost? Sería asi?

Comment: @Juan el error aparece en el local y en la nube